# R - Error when knitting an Rmd file which has code to knit another Rmd file (duplicate "setup" chunk name)

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I am trying to knit an `.Rmd` file (*file2*) with `rmarkdown::render()` from within another `.Rmd` file (*file1*).

If I run the chunk in *file1* that renders *file2* interactively from *file1*, *file2* is rendered fine.

If I knit *file1* I get this error:

```
Error in parse_block(g[-1], g[1], params.src, markdown_mode) : 
  Duplicate chunk label 'setup', which has been used for the chunk:
...
```

How can I knit `.Rmd` files from other `.Rmd` files?

This is the MWE content of *file1* and *file2*:

*file1*:

````
---
title: "File 1"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
knitr::opts_knit$set(root.dir = here::here())
```

# Let's knit it

```{r knit-it}
rmarkdown::render("./file2.Rmd", envir = new.env())
```
````

*file2*:

````
---
title: "File 2"
output: github_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
knitr::opts_knit$set(root.dir = here::here())
```

# Knit me

```{r random}
rnorm(2)
```
````

Comment: Which file is `knit-me.Rmd` ? I thought your two files are called `file1.Rmd` and `file2.Rmd`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should render the other file in another R session, e.g.,

```r
xfun::Rscript_call(rmarkdown::render, list("./file2.Rmd"))
```